# most efficient algorithm to set the twin pointer

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, time-complexity, adjacency-list

In an adjacency list representation of an undirected simple graph G = (V, E), each edge (u, v) has two adjacency list entries: [v] in the adjacency list of u, and [u] in the adjacency list of v. These are called twins of each other. A twin pointer is a pointer from an adjacency list entry to its twin. If |E| = m and |V| = n, and the memory size is not a constraint, what is the time complexity of the most efficient algorithm to set the twin pointer in each entry in each adjacency list?

1. Θ(n^2)
2. Θ(m+n)
3. Θ(m^2)
4. Θ(n^4)

---

My attempt :

Official answer is given Θ(m+n). Twin Pointers can be setup by keeping track of parent node in BFS or DFS of graph.

> Can you give most efficient algorithm to set the twin pointer in each entry in each adjacency list?

Comment: Do you mean the following: Initially, the adjacency lists are given with the twin pointers uninitialized - what is the time complexity to initialize the twin pointers?

Comment: @Codor, Can you give algorithm as he asked in question. IMO: it's according either BFS or DFS, rt?

Comment: Yes I think so, it should be Θ(m+n) then (i.e. linear time).

Answer (score 0):

Since memory is not a constraint here, first we will create a data structure for storing the address of adjacency entries for each  adjacency list. For faster retrieval we will create a 2D array of pointers of size (n2) which will point to  adjacency entries in the graph.
If there is an edge between u and v, then our data structure A[u][v] contains the address of the adjacency entry of v in the  adjacency list of u. Otherwise it can be NULL. For more clear picture, refer to the image given below.

Comment: "_refer to the image given below_" Which image?

Answer (score 0):

To represent a graph, if we use matrix, then the time complexity of the most efficient algorithm to set the twin pointer will be `O(n2).` Now, if we use the Adjacency list, it will be:

```
2(Edges + Vertices) = 2(m+n) = O(m+n).
```

Therefore option (**B)** is the right answer.